# Pivoting rows with aggregates other than SUM?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to pivot rows in MySQL, with aggregates other than SUM?
I've been looking online, and through my courses book. But, I cannot find anything.

Comment: yes you can pivot in mysql. but you need to post some data first with desired result

Comment: You can pivot with `COUNT()` also, if the inner expression returns NULL to eliminate rows. Depends on your need.

Comment: MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` keyword though, if that is what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - yes you can pivot use other aggregates depending on the type of query you need to perform - each can serve a specialized purpose.

### Using `COUNT()` to count up rows (like `SUM()`)

Because aggregate functions eliminate `NULL` values, you will sometimes encounter a pattern similar to the `SUM(CASE...)` you are probably accustomed to seeing (whose expression returns a 1 or 0, which get added up).  Instead of using a `SUM()` aggregate in this method, you can use a `COUNT()` instead, provided its expression returns a value (any value) or a `NULL`.  The `NULL`s get eliminated, and the `COUNT()` counts up the returned non-null rows. This is only useful for counting up values though

Here's an example counting up rows per group where `val = 1`, using a `COUNT()` aggregate. Suppose you have the following table and you want the results as columns `a, b`.

```
group value
 a     1
 a     1
 a     2
 b     1
 b     2
```

#### Using `COUNT()`

```
SELECT 
  `group`,
  /* the aggregate eliminates NULLs (rows where val <> 1) */
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `group` = 'a' THEN val ELSE NULL END) AS `a`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `group` = 'b' THEN val ELSE NULL END) AS `b`
FROM pivot
WHERE val = 1
```

Result:

```
 a      b
-------------
 2      1
```

Demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4585/7

That is basically the same as can be done with `SUM()` and zeros and ones:

#### Using `SUM()` like you've probably seen accomplishes the same thing:

```
SELECT 
  /* the aggregate eliminates NULLs (rows where val <> 1) */
  SUM(CASE WHEN `group` = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `a`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `group` = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `b`
FROM pivot
WHERE val = 1
```

Demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4585/8

---

### Using `MAX()` to pivot a list of key/value pairs:

Occasionally, you just want to change a 1-to-1 mapping from rows to columns. This is useful if you needed to flatten out a list of key/value pairs for example.  Suppose you had a table like this, where there will only ever be one row per column you want to pivot out:

```
key    value
------------
k1     v1
k2     v2
k3     v3
```

... and you want a result like this:

```
k1  k2  k3
-----------
v1  v2  v3
```

In this case, you can use a `MAX()` or `MIN()` aggregate, because again since the NULL values will get eliminated by the aggregate, only the one that actually has a non-null will be returned, and hence be the `MAX()`.

So whi2le this query would pivot them but result in 3 rows, with only one non-null per row:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN `key` = 'k1' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END AS `k1`,
  CASE WHEN `key` = 'k2' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END AS `k2`,
  CASE WHEN `key` = 'k3' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END AS `k3`
FROM key_value
```

Result:

```
k1   k2   k3
---------------
v1   NULL NULL
NULL v2   NULL
NULL NULL v3
```

Demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/813b3/5

By using a `MAX()` aggregate, you effectively collapse it down to one row by getting rid of the `NULL`s

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN `key` = 'k1' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END) AS `k1`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `key` = 'k2' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END) AS `k2`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `key` = 'k3' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END) AS `k3`
FROM key_value
```

Gives the result we wanted - one row pivoted out:

```
k1  k2  k3
-----------
v1  v2  v3
```

Demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/813b3/4